# Is there a way to resolve what appears to be a broken png file after build in unity2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

clear flags = solid color

texture quality = full res

unity version = 2018.4.0f1

[image]

Build was done by PC version.

This program will be used in a special environment, so it has a resolution of 3000 x 1875.

The monitor supports up to 1920 x 1080

Why did this happen?

Comment: Visual errors like that usually happen when the size of the image is not properly managed/interpretted.  Are you displaying the image with standard Unity tools?

Comment: i used only unity standard tool

Comment: What is the texture type (you can find it in Inspector) and the precise size of the image?

Comment: I solved this problem by deleting a high-resolution image animation sequence.
Thank you for your help.